# Proof that $A+A^T$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A \in \mathbb R^{10,10}$, $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{7}\in \mathbb R^{10}$ which are linearly independent vectors and $Ax_{1}=Ax_{2}=...=Ax_{7}$. Proof that $A+A^T$ is singular (not invertible)

I am trying to do this task in two different ways and none of them works. 

Firstly I wanted to show that $$\det (A+A^T)  = 0  $$
but there is no nice formula for $\det A + B $ so probably it is wrong way.

From the other hand I have that idea:

Assume that exists $B$ such that
$$ B\cdot(A+A^T) = I_n$$
and now I wanted to proof that $$\ker A^T \subset \ker A$$ then I could easly fail that assumption. But unfortunately It (my sub-proof) seems to be false theorem so... have somebody any idea how to solve this task?

Comment: you mean is not invertible ? since $\det(B) = 0$ means $B$ is not invertible

Comment: Sorry - I mean irvertible

Comment: What is `irvertible`?

Comment: @MathLover full rank (for square matrices). Strictly speaking, $M$ is invertible if there exists $M^{-1}$ such that $MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M = I$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the conclusion should be that $A+A^T$ is **not** invertible. Note that the range of $A$ is spanned by
$$
\langle Ax_1,Ax_2,\ldots , Ax_{10}\rangle =\langle Ax_7,Ax_8,Ax_{9}, Ax_{10}\rangle,
$$ which implies that the rank of $A$ is at most $4$. By the rank theorem, $A^T$ has the same rank as $A$. This implies that $A+A^T$ has rank at most $\text{rk}(A)+\text{rk}(A^T)\le 8<10$, which says that $A+A^T$ is not invertible.

Comment: that's a nice proof!

Comment: @Surb Thank you :-)

Comment: Made all the nicer by the fact its strategy also makes obvious why the original problem equated seven vectors; with just six, this proof wouldn't have worked.

Comment: So if $\ker A$ has only $\vec{0}$ then $A$ is irvertible?

Comment: @VirtualUser Yes, if $\ker A =(\vec0 )$, then $A$ is injective, and for a square matrix, injectivity is the same as bijectivity.

Comment: Wow, thanks, very nice proof